# How to insert a different value on a column if. id <=10 or I'd <=20?

Tags: php

$id=$_POST['ID] ,    $class=$_POST['CLASS'];       $id= 20;
If ($id <=10) { SQL= "insert into table( ID , CLASS)VALUES('$a', A);}    Else ($id <=20){
SQL= "insert into table (ID, CLASS) VALUES ('$a' , B);
} $result=MySQL_query($SQL);

Comment: `$id= 20; if ($id <=10) {` ... That will *always* be false.  It's not really clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I want to make an  auto generated Sectioning , like if the students Id from 1- 10  they will be on section A  and students id from 11-20 will belong to Section B;  I  am having trouble on how to insert it to database;

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to use different tables for different user ID ranges. If you are doing this for performance and database sizing, forget it, you are wasting your time, SQL database can have millions of rows with no issues, trying to split into different tables just causes unneeded complexity.

But to answer the question, something like this is all you need:

```
if ($userID > "9")
{
    $table = "A";

}   else { 

    $table = "B";
 }

} 

SQL= INSERT INTO $table ( field1, field2,...fieldN ) VALUES ( value1, value2,...valueN );
```